# Recognize special characters

Tags: regex, unicode, special-characters, antlr, antlr4

I've got a little question (I've used Google before):
Is there a way, how to match all special unicode characters except quotes?

I have this code:

```
STRING:     '"' (NUMBER|LETTER|' '|'!'|'?'|':'|'.'|'/'|'*')* '"';

fragment LETTER: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z');
fragment DIGIT:  ('0'..'9');
```

Is there more efficient way?

Thanks for feedback!

Comment: What makes a character "special"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~["]`, or the old v3 style `~'"'`, matches any character except a quote.

If you also want to exclude line breaks, do something like this:

```
STRING : '"' ~["\r\n]* '"';
```

From [the official docs](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules):

> `~x`
>
> Match any single character not in the set described by `x`. Set `x` can be a single character literal, a range, or a subrule set like `~(’x’|’y’|’z’)` or `~[xyz]`. Here is a rule that uses `~` to match any character other than characters using `~[\r\n]*`:
>
> ```
> COMMENT : '#' ~[\r\n]* '\r'? '\n' -> skip ;
> ```

Comment: That isn't working properly, when I type 'print "Hello world!"', it says that 'line 1:6 token recognition error at: '"He'
line 1:18 token recognition error at: '!'
line 1:19 token recognition error at: '"\n''

Comment: @DrunkCoder, you're not using ANTLR3, right? If you're using v4, I guess some other rule is causing things to fail: could you post your entire grammar in that case? Also see the link to the official docs.